# TabControl in TabPage

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I got a following problem:
I add a dynamically created `TabControl` to a tabpage (which is also dynamically created). When I try to add another tabpage with another tabcontrol, it acts like there's no new `TabControl` added to the new `TabPage`. In fact, it does not add anything. What should I do? Here's a code where I create a `TabPage`:

```
    Dim tbstate As New TabPage
    tbstate.ContextMenuStrip = QuestEd.cmsState
    tbstate.Text = String.Format("State: {0}", txtState.Text)
    QuestEd.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbstate)
    txtState.Text = Nothing
    tbstate.Select()
    QuestEd.RefreshData()
    Me.Dispose()
```

And here is the code where I create a new `TabControl` for this `TabPage`

```
Public newtab As New TabControl
     ...
            If QuestEd.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count = 0 Then
                newtab.Parent = QuestEd.TabControl1.SelectedTab
                newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                QuestEd.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newtab)
                QuestEd.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Refresh()
                newtab.TabPages.Add(String.Format("When: {0}", typ))
            Else
                newtab.TabPages.Add(String.Format("When: {0}", typ))
            End If
```

What do I do wrong? Can somebody suggest me how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: No. I forgot to add an explanation what is a newtab. newtab is a new Tabcontrol. I corrected the code, thanks ;)

Comment: Quacks like the standard VB.NET trap.  QuestEd is a *type*, not an object reference to the form that the user is actually looking at.  And the code is running on a worker thread.  So it will create a *new* instance of the QuestEd form class, one you can't see because its Show() method was never called.  Blind guess of course, the shoe fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran a quick test of your code. I am guessing since you have  Public visibility on your newtab that you are declaring it at the Class level. Your code does work, it does add a new TabControl on a TabPage. In reading Hans's comment he most likely is correct on what is going on, If you are using the class name of the Form instead of an Instance Name then you would not see anything. If you are trying to add these controls from another form you will need to pass in the instance of the form that you are adding it to. Without seeing how your are structuring your project it is just a wild guess.

My Example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim newtab As New TabControl
    Dim typ As String = "Hello"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tbstate As New TabPage
        Dim tbstate1 As New TabPage
        tbstate.Text = String.Format("State: {0}", "My Test")
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbstate)
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbstate1)
        tbstate.Select()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count = 0 Then
            newtab = New TabControl
            newtab.Parent = TabControl1.SelectedTab
            newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newtab)
            TabControl1.SelectedTab.Refresh()
            newtab.TabPages.Add(String.Format("When: {0}", typ))
        Else
            DirectCast(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0), TabControl).TabPages.Add(New TabPage(String.Format("When: {0}", typ)))            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I tried Your code and it works, but only for one page in TabControl1. When I add another tabpage to TabControl1 it imports newtab control to it and previously created page becomes clear. And forgive me, but I'm not into specialistic terminology so I don't understant what You try to say. Would You mind use another words? :)

Comment: Just modified the code to allow multiple TabControls.  As far as rephrasing what I said. You have a basic class which is your form, you create an (instance) of the form when you do something like `Dim myForm as new Form1` myForm is the instance, Form1 is the class. Visual Basic will use a default instance if you use the Class name, it is not what you are looking at therefore you do not see your controls.

Comment: Thanks for Your help :) I made it just by function. Also thank You for sharing an useful knowledge with me. Have a nice day.